# Open Acrobat Reader with Sharepoint File from command line

Tags: sharepoint, command-line, acrobat, reader

Acrobat Reader can open file form Sharepoint using an URL.
But this does not work if I try it from command line.

I tried:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "https://int-dms.fma.llv.li/sites/Dossier30392/Shared Documents/test.pdf"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "https://int-dms.fma.llv.li/sites/Dossier30392/Shared%20Documents/test.pdf"

Any ideas how to get this done?